# Doctrine query failing to find records when searching by date

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

We have a `SalesOrder` entity with `shippingDateTime`, I am passing a `$startDate` and `$endDate` `DateTime` object to the query builder like this:

```
/**
 * @param \DateTime      $startDate
 * @param \DateTime|null $endDate
 * 
 * @return array|null
 */
public function getShippedOrdersByDateRange(\DateTime $startDate, ?\DateTime $endDate = null): ?array
{
    $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');

    $builder->select('o')
        ->where('o.shippedDateTime >= :startDate')
        ->andWhere('o.shipped = true')
        ->andWhere('o.deleted = false')
        ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate, Type::DATE);

    if (!\is_null($endDate)) {
        $builder->andWhere('o.shippedDateTime <= :endDate')
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate, Type::DATE);
    }

    return $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Now there are Sales orders with the `shippedDateTime` as `2020-05-12` and `2020-05-13` but if I try the following I get weird results:

Start Date: `2020-05-12`
End Date: `2020-05-12`

No results, even though the query says `startDate >=` and `endDate <=` so then I should have 1 result for 12th may!

Start Date: `2020-05-12`
End Date: `2020-05-13`

Gives me 1 result with the shipping date as 12th May instead of 2 results one with 12th and one with 13th!

So I'm a bit stumped as the why the query is ignoring the fact I am asking for the end date as SMALLER OR EQUAL TO, so if I pass over 2020-05-12 as both start and end date, shouldn't the query be giving me results where the shipped date is greater than or equal to the 12th and smaller than or equal to the 12th, meaning the same day??

In the database they are just stored as standard mysql `datetime` fields such as `2020-05-12 12:00:00`

It doesn't make sense for a user to have to set 1 day higher on the end date if they just want a single day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a a `Type::DATE` parameter, but you have `DateTime` columns in your database.

In the end, your query would get evaluated to:

```sql
WHERE '2020-05-12 12:00:00' >= '2020-05-12'
    AND '2020-05-12 12:00:00' <= '2020-05-12'
```

By omitting the time for the compared values; you get `00:00:00` times.

The first part of the predicate evaluates to `true` (`2020-05-12 12:00:00` **is**  greater than `2020-05-12 00:00:00`), but the second logically fails (`2020-05-12 12:00:00` **is not**  less than `2020-05-12 00:00:00`)

`(true && false) === false`.

Exactly the same for your other example.

If you want to use `<=`, then you would have to pass a date time (`Type::DateTime`) value for the second part of the predicate, specifying `23:59:59` for the time part.

But it's easier just to use `<` and compare with the date of the date you are not interested in, and very easy to understand.

Comment: ut it's easier just to use < and compare with the date of the date you are not interested in, and very easy to understand." what do you mean by this? this means that the user has to select the end date a day in advance, but i do get what you mean about the time

Comment: If want records on date N, you look for “N+1”; that’s what I mean. Which is generally easy. But In the end whatever way you prefer doing it. I was just explaining why you got the results you got.

Comment: Yeh good point, for now i think the simplest solution would be $endDate->setTime(23,59,59)  before it's used. Stupid mistake using datetime, well, laziness really! Thanks dude.